# How to set events on Listview in Titanium using XML Alloy Markup

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

From [here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160894/listview-multiple-itemclick-and-longpress-event) I know events cannot be set on the ListView or on the ListItem(Data) directly. But can be set as below code.

```
var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
  // …
  templates: {
    "simple": {
      // …
      events: {
        "longpress": function (event) {
          Ti.API.warn(event.itemId); // Works! ;)
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But my question is how can I set the same using XML Mark up. My listview is like this

```
<ListView   id="messageList" onItemclick="openPagerMessageDetails"  >
    <Templates   >
        <ItemTemplate     id="lstTemplate" name="messageListtemplate" >
            <View  id="myCustomView" ></View>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </Templates>
    <ListSection   id="lstSection" ></ListSection>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is quite old, but according to [Appcelerator Wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Alloy+ListView+Guide#AlloyListViewGuide-HandlingEventsonTemplateViews), when you have your template in view, you can add an event listener to particular view as usual by adding `onClick=""` (I assume it works with other events as well).

```
<Templates>
    <ItemTemplate id="lstTemplate" name="messageListtemplate">
        <View id="myCustomView" onClick="doClick" ></View>
    </ItemTemplate>
</Templates>
```